# Find number of continuous subarray having sum zero

Tags: algorithm

You have given a array and You have to give number of continuous subarray which the sum is zero.

```
example:
1)  0 ,1,-1,0 => 6 {{0},{1,-1},{0,1,-1},{1,-1,0},{0}};
2)  5, 2, -2, 5 ,-5, 9 => 3.
```

With O(n^2) it can be done.I am trying to find the solution below this complexity.

Comment: I try with http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-subarray-with-given-sum/ but it doesn't solve my case.

Comment: In your first example {0} looks to be repetitive. and also one could be {0,1,-1,0}

Comment: correct and {0} are consider twice duplication of subset are allowed

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't know what the complexity of my suggestion would be but i have an idea :)
What you can do is try to reduce element from main array which are not able to contribute for you solution 
suppose elements are `-10, 5, 2, -2, 5,7 ,-5, 9,11,19`
so you can see that `-10,9,11 and 19` are element
that are never gone be useful to make `sum 0` in your case
so try to remove `-10,9,11, and 19` from your main array
to do this what you can do is

```
1) create two sub array from your main array  
`positive {5,7,2,9,11,19}` and `negative {-10,-2,-5}`   
2) remove element from positive array which does not satisfy condition
   condition -> value should be construct from negative arrays element  
   or sum of  its elements  
   ie.   
       5 = -5 //so keep it //don't consider the sign  
       7 = (-5 + -2 ) // keep  
       2 = -2 // keep
       9 // cannot be construct using -10,-2,-5  
       same for all 11 and 19
3) remove element form negative array which does not satisfy condition
      condition -> value should be construct from positive arrays element  
       or sum of  its elements   
  i.e. -10 // cannot be construct so discard  
       -2 = 2 // keep  
       -5 = 5 // keep
```

so finally you got an array which contains -2,-5,5,7,2 create all possible sub array form it and check for sum = 0
(Note if your input array contains 0 add all 0's in final array)

Comment: 1) If all elements are only -1 and 1, then your pruning gives nothing.
2) Complexity is uncertain, but no less than O(N^2).

Comment: @stgatilov if there data contains only useful elements like you say -1 and 1 then this is not helpful and not gone reduce any complexity but consider the data set which contains many non required elements (which is also idle situation) in that case this will reduce complexity for sure :)

Answer (score 9):

Consider S[0..N] - [prefix sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) of your array, i.e. S[k] = A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[k-1] for k from 0 to N.

Now sum of elements from L to R-1 is zero if and only if S[R] = S[L]. It means that you have to find number of indices 0 <= L < R <= N such that S[L] = S[R].

This problem can be solved with a hash table. Iterate over elements of S[] while maintaining for each value X number of times it was met in the already processed part of S[]. These counts should be stored in a hash map, where the number X is a key, and the count H[X] is the value. When you meet a new elements S[i], add H[S[i]] to your answer (these account for substrings ending with (i-1)-st element), then increment H[S[i]] by one.

Note that if sum of absolute values of array elements is small, you can use a simple array instead of hash table. The complexity is linear on average.

Here is the code:

```
long long CountZeroSubstrings(vector<int> A) {
    int n = A.size();

    vector<long long> S(n+1, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        S[i+1] = S[i] + A[i];

    long long answer = 0;
    unordered_map<long long, int> H;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (H.count(S[i]))
            answer += H[S[i]];
        H[S[i]]++;      
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in linear time by keeping a hash table of sums reached during the array traversal. The number of subsets can then be directly calculated from the counts of revisited sums.

Haskell version:

```hs
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.List (foldl')

f = foldl' (\b a -> b + div (a * (a + 1)) 2) 0 . M.elems . snd
  . foldl' (\(s,m) x -> let s' = s + x in case M.lookup s' m of 
                          Nothing   -> (s',M.insert s' 0 m)
                          otherwise -> (s',M.adjust (+1) s' m)) (0,M.fromList[(0,0)])
```

Output:

```
*Main> f [0,1,-1,0]
6

*Main> f [5,2,-2,5,-5,9]
3

*Main> f [0,0,0,0]
10

*Main> f [0,1,0,0]
4

*Main> f [0,1,0,0,2,3,-3]
5

*Main> f [0,1,-1,0,0,2,3,-3]
11
```

Comment: Given array of N zeros, each nonempty subarray has zero sum, so the answer must be N*(N+1)/2. However, your solution only returns numbers in form (2^s - 1). Isn't it wrong?
Also, the answer for the first array seems to be 6.

Comment: @stgatilov you are correct - I made a mistake and counted all subsets, not all continuous subsets - thanks. I amended the formula.

Answer (score 1):

C# version of @stgatilov answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31489960/3087417 with readable variables:

```
        int[] sums = new int[arr.Count() + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count(); i++)
            sums[i + 1] = sums[i] + arr[i];

        int numberOfFragments = 0;
        Dictionary<int, int> sumToNumberOfRepetitions = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach (int item in sums)
        {
            if (sumToNumberOfRepetitions.ContainsKey(item))
                numberOfFragments += sumToNumberOfRepetitions[item];
            else
                sumToNumberOfRepetitions.Add(item, 0);

            sumToNumberOfRepetitions[item]++;
        }

        return numberOfFragments;
```

If you want to have sum not only zero but any number k, here is the hint:

```
            int numToFind = currentSum - k;
            if (sumToNumberOfRepetitions.ContainsKey(numToFind))
                numberOfFragments += sumToNumberOfRepetitions[numToFind];
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel it can be solved using DP:
Let the state be :
DP[i][j]  represents the number of ways j can be formed using all the subarrays ending at i!

**Transitions:**

for every element in the initial step ,

Increase the number of ways to form `Element[i]` using i elements by 1 i.e. using the subarray of length 1 starting from i and ending with i i.e

```
DP[i][Element[i]]++;
```

then for every j in Range [ -Mod(highest Magnitude of any element ) , Mod(highest Magnitude of any element) ]

```
DP[i][j]+=DP[i-1][j-Element[i]];
```

Then your answer will be the sum of all the DP[i][0] (Number of ways to form 0 using subarrays ending at i ) where i varies from 1 to Number of elements

**Complexity** is O(MOD highest magnitude of any element * Number of Elements)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.techiedelight.com/find-sub-array-with-0-sum/

This would be an exact solution.

```py
# Utility function to insert <key, value> into the dict
def insert(dict, key, value):
 
    # if the key is seen for the first time, initialize the list
    dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
 
 
# Function to print all sub-lists with 0 sum present
# in the given list
def printallSublists(A):
 
    # create an empty -dict to store ending index of all
    # sub-lists having same sum
    dict = {}
 
    # insert (0, -1) pair into the dict to handle the case when
    # sub-list with 0 sum starts from index 0
    insert(dict, 0, -1)
 
    result = 0
    sum = 0
 
    # traverse the given list
    for i in range(len(A)):
 
        # sum of elements so far
        sum += A[i]
 
        # if sum is seen before, there exists at-least one
        # sub-list with 0 sum
        if sum in dict:
 
            list = dict.get(sum)
            result += len(list)
            # find all sub-lists with same sum
            for value in list:
                print("Sublist is", (value + 1, i))
 
        # insert (sum so far, current index) pair into the -dict
        insert(dict, sum, i)

    print("length :", result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    A = [0, 1, 2, -3, 0, 2, -2]
 
    printallSublists(A)
```